# How to show $BE=EF$?

Tags: geometry

As shown in the figure , $ABCD$  is a trapezoid，$AD\parallel BC$ , $\angle C=45^{\circ}$, $AB=AD=4$ ，$E$ is a point on the line $DA$ , $EF\perp BE$ and $AB\perp AD$.

Show: $BE=EF$.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "half line"?

Comment: @DonAntonio I believe he means the ray $DA$.

Comment: Is F a point on the line DC?

Comment: @nadia-liza Yes.

Comment: @Railgun The segment $AB$ appears perpendicular to $AD$ by looking at the diagram, so, just to clarify (in case you forgot to mention it), is $AB\perp AD$ ?

Comment: @DavidH, that sounds logical. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to mention the fact that $AB\perp AD$. I've created a diagram on GeoGebra without making the angle between $AB$ and $AD$ perpendicular and I got that $BE$ was far from being equal to $EF$. When I made it perpendicular, the equality was satisfied. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as mathh suggested, you need $AD \perp BC$ (which is part of the conclusion), or else your conclusion need not actually be true. This is because you can construct a diagram with your given conditions without the extra condition; however, $BE = EF$ also implies $AD \perp BC$ given your diagram.

Since we know $\triangle BEF$ is a right triangle, it suffices to show $\angle EBF = 45^{\circ}$.

Draw the line $BD$, then $\triangle ABD$ is a right triangle, and since it is isosceles we know $\angle ABD = 45^{\circ}$, so $\angle DBC = 45^{\circ}$ as well. Then $\triangle DBC$ is a right triangle as well. Since the opposite angles of the quadrilateral $BEFD$ add to $180^{\circ}$ we know it is cyclic.

So $\angle EBF = \angle EDF$ which is equal to $\angle C = 45^{\circ}$ (since $AD$ and $BC$ are parallel), and we are done.